# How to use hardcoded file path names with sandbox

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, sandbox

Ok, yes I know now that you can not use hardcoded paths with sandbox. Up to this point I have not delt with sandbox, so I never encountered it.

I have a Coredata App (Mac OSx) and I used the default save code and the default path location (user/...../applicationsupport/... This, of coarse, is not acceptable in the sandbox.

Without requiring the user to manually open the data file each time the program is launched, is there another way to deal with this?

I would appreciate any input/suggestions.

Thanks You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandbox doesn't mean there isn't any access to files and folders without user selection. As it said in [App Sandbox in Depth article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW4) there's container directory you still having access to.

For taking a path to your `Application Support`-directory you should use the same code whenever you use Sandboxing or not.

```
+ (NSString *)executableName
  {
   NSString *executableName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
   if(!executableName || executableName.length==0)
      return nil;
   return executableName;
  }

- (NSString *)findOrCreateDirectory:(NSSearchPathDirectory)searchPathDirectory
                           inDomain:(NSSearchPathDomainMask)domainMask
                appendPathComponent:(NSString *)appendComponent
                              error:(NSError **)errorOut
  {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(searchPathDirectory,domainMask,YES);
   if ([paths count]==0)
      return nil;
   NSString *resolvedPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   if (appendComponent)
      resolvedPath = [resolvedPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:appendComponent];
   NSError *error;
   BOOL success = [self createDirectoryAtPath:resolvedPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
   if (!success)
     {
      if (errorOut)
         *errorOut = error;
      return nil;
     }
   return resolvedPath;
  }

- (NSString *)applicationSupportDirectory
  {
   NSError *error;
   NSString *result = [self findOrCreateDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                              appendPathComponent:[self executableName] error:&error];
   if (error)
      return nil;
   return result;
  }
```

Comment: Astoria - thanks your the reply. Although I was creating/accessing paths similar to your code, I forgot about the `container`. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction - all is working good now.