# How to grant file system access outside of container?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sandbox

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW7), for an app to access the file system outside of its container, and outside of the directories listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW17), it needs to specify a File Access Temporary Exceptions Entitlement.

My app needs to read and write some files in `~/Library/Application Support/`, so I set the `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write` value to `/Library/Application Support/` in the app's `.entitlement` plist.

Now my app is able to read files from `~/Library/Application Support/` if the path is hardcoded like this:

```swift
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myUsername/Library/Application Support/path/to/somefile.txt")
let fileContent = try! String(contentsOf: filePath, encoding: .ascii)
```

However, if I do it like the following, it wouldn't work:

```swift
let filePathString = "~/Library/Application Support/path/to/somefile.txt"
let expandedFilePathString = NSString(string: filePathString).expandingTildeInPath
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: expandedFilePathString)
let fileContent = try! String(contentsOf: filePath, encoding: .ascii) // Error

// alternatively
let applicationSupportPath = try! FileManager.default.url(
    for: .applicationSupportDirectory,
    in: .userDomainMask,
    appropriateFor: nil,
    create: false
)
let filePath = applicationSupportPath.appendingPathComponent("path/to/somefile.txt")
let fileContent = try! String(contentsOf: filePath, encoding: .ascii) // Error
```

Both errors are because the app is trying to access a path in the container: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “somefile.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/myUsername/Library/Containers/my.bundle.id/Data/Library/Application Support/path/to/somefile.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c71c20 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`.

In addition, `FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser` returns `/Users/myUsername/Library/Containers/my.bundle.id/Data/`.

My question: How do I grant my app access to file system outside of its container, without hard-coding the path?

[My previous quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60275946/how-to-grant-disk-access-to-app-when-its-run-through-xcode) on the same topic has been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205089/how-to-use-hardcoded-file-path-names-with-sandbox). However, the "duplicated" question is about hard-coded paths, whereas my question is about non-hard-coded paths. Also, the "duplicated" question is in Objective-C, whereas my question is in Swift.

Answer (score 5):

Giving `/` to `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write` is what I do for that.

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
    <array>
        <string>/</string>
    </array>
```

Yes it’s an absolute path but it’s a pretty simple and universal one.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it in my code, but it didn't work for me. Is adding `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write` to the entitlement plist the only thing you did to make it work for you?

Comment: Yes along with the array containing the string.

Comment: Also if you are only trying to get into `~/Library` without knowing the absolute path you may do that in programming by taking the returned intra-container data path the runtime sees as HOME and slide the terminator over from the end to get rid of the suffix.  Of course taking care with unintended truncation.

Comment: https://github.com/Beep6581/RawTherapee/blob/85bffa10381450bee541283616e3572665f12314/rtgui/options.cc#L2273-L2281

Comment: @RichardBarber : Did you find out, how to access files outside the container? I added "com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write" along with the array containing the path in the entitlement file.  It does not work - is there anything else to do?

Comment: @mica Nope, I believe this ability requires codesign entitlement within the typical secured runtime environment.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue.
I would access to outside of container's folder.
this is help to me

```
let applicationSupportFolder = "/Users/\(NSUserName())/Library/Application Support"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).